# Angular observable and service

Tags: angular, typescript

**post-create.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output} from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { Post } from '../post.model';
import { PostsService } from "../posts.service";


 @Component({
    selector: 'app-post-create',
    templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.css']
 })

export class PostCreateComponent {
    enteredContent = '';
    enteredTitle = '';

    constructor(public postsService: PostsService){}

    onAddPost(form: NgForm){
        if(form.invalid){
            return;
        }
        this.postsService.addPost(form.value.title, form.value.content);
        form.resetForm();
    }
}
```

**posts.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Post } from "./post.model";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PostsService {
    private posts: Post[]= [];

    getPosts(){
        return this.posts;
    }

    addPost(title: string, content: string){
        const post: Post = {title: title, content: content};
        this.posts.push(post);
    }
}
```

post-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Post } from "../post.model";
import { PostsService } from "../posts.service";

 @Component({
    selector: 'app-post-list',
    templateUrl: './post-list.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
 })

export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Post[] = [];

    constructor(public postsService: PostsService){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.posts = this.postsService.getPosts();
    }
 }
```

As you  can see , I have not implemented observable to observe the change in post in service  which is used in **post-list.component.ts** to display the list.I was under the impression that observable is required to look for the changes, however even without using observable as you see in code text above, it was working fine. How was it working without observable? **ngOnInit** at **post-list.component.ts** was running on each render? I used the **console.log** on **ngOnInit** at **post-list.component.ts**, it wasn't logging each time I created post, but list was getting rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How was it working without observable?

In your ngOnInit, you're assigning `this.posts = this.postsService.getPosts();` (which amounts to `this.posts = this.postsService.posts`. Since `posts` is an object, this assignment creates not a copy, but simply another reference to the same object. Updating one, you're updating another, because another *is* the same object.

Consider trivial example:

```js
const alice = { name: "Alice" };
const bob = alice;
bob.name = "Bob";

console.log(alice.name);
```

But this is not a good way of synchronizing values in Angular. One reason, it'll slip past detection if you use onPush change detection strategy. Another, the live link between the objects *isn't* obvious.